What should we do about [bicep]?
The tag bicep has 20 questions, and every single one of them really means azure-bicep. I'm not sure if that means we should make it a synonym or burninate it or do nothing.

Retag those questions. This is not a burnination, people just tagged it wrong.

12 of those 20 were overlapping with azure-bicep so the tags are now merged and there's a synonym to prevent it from happening again.
